# Django list of objects doesn't render properly when using a form on the same page

Tags: django, listview, render

I have developed a very simple Django app about music bands and their members (complete code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MwaC-_PchU6eBrwO01OaDivIF52S0L1D/view?usp=sharing). I used just the simple SQLlite3 database for my objects. I would appreciate help with rendering object lists when they need to be shown together with forms. They do render properly in templates that show just them, but not when a form is used on the same page with an object list.

What I want is to display, say, a list of bands from the database in the middle column. It shows them properly when I render just that (i.e. when I click the Bands link). However, when I click Add band in the right-hand column and hope the list to remain in the middle column, it suddenly shrinks as if there were no Band objects in the database.

In learning Django, I used the official Django tutorial, as well as the one provided by Mozilla (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Tutorial_local_library_website), but could not figure out what I'm doing wrong.

The code below shows the relevant parts of the code. The link above takes you to the complete code (zipped), where the relevant HTML templates are included as well. I used Python 3.7, Django 2.2, and PyCharm 2019.2.

```py
    # Model:
    class Band(models.Model):
        rock = [
            [False, 'no'],
            [True, 'yes']
        ]

        name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='unknown')
        country = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='USA')
        is_rock = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Rock 'n' roll",
                                            choices=rock,
                                            default=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name + ', ' + self.country + (" (rock 'n' roll)" if self.is_rock else ' (other)')

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            """Returns the URL to access a particular band.
            Enables specific Festival pages in admin to include "View on site" button.
            """

            return reverse('band-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

    # View:

    class BandListView(ListView):
        model = Band
        template_name = 'band/band_list.html'
        paginate_by = 10

        def get_queryset(self):
            return Band.objects.all()
```

I suspect there is something wrong with the {% if band_list %} parts in the band_list.html and band_form.html templates I have included in the complete code linked above. I expected the list of bands to render the same way regardless of whether the form is rendered on the right side or not.

Any help and suggestion would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: That's not the relevant parts of the code, and certainly no-one here is going to download your zip file to find them. How is the form being added to that view? And what does the template look like?

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Thanks, Daniel. For some strange reasons, the template I entered in my question did not show up. Here it is again:

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Thanks, Daniel. The template is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JHbGeUXIBIhZrxEt2sIkyh87JnJzSeX-xCvWGIp5_HM), and it opens when the user clicks _Add band_ in [this one](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1c8QstYtgsOUk_RsiDQtawXQvJH--7Ad4ql4y-toSayA/edit?usp=sharing). The relevant urlpattern is: `path('bands/create/', views.BandCreate.as_view(), name='band-create')`. The url pattern corresponding to the band-list view is: `path('bands/', views.BandListView.as_view(), name='band-list')`.

Comment: Those look the same. But I still don't understand your question. Where is the BandCreate view? Does it send a `band_list` to the template?

Comment: @DanielRoseman: The BandCreate view is extremely simple - it's [here, in the views.py](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gejmJKz6xLklVXjorpw_ByEDpfUYui8FM0_6X9vnvs4). As you can see, it's just a 2-line class-based view. What puzzles me the most is the fact that my simple app actually works completely OK except for that one detail.

Comment: But why does this puzzle you? As I said, you're not passing the list of bands to the template in that view. (And please stop posting your code in Google docs; post it here.)

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Could you, please suggest how exactly to pass the list of bands to the template in that view (some simple code would be most helpful)? Note that I am a Django LEARNER, that's why I'm asking for this help. Thanks again in advance.